# Recurrence relations exercise

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

> Consider the sequence $(c_n)_{n \ge 0 }$  defined by the recurrence relation $c_{n+2}-2c_{n+1}-3c_n=2^{n+2}$, for $n \ge 0$. Determinate $c_n$.

So far I got

$(1-2x-3x^2)C(x)=P(x)+ \sum_{n \ge 0}(c_{n+2}-2c_{n+1}-3c_n)x^n$
$\Leftrightarrow$

$(1-2x-3x^2)C(x)=P(x)+\sum_{n \ge 0}(2^{n+2})x^n$

How should I proceed? Any Hint would be good so I can try to finish it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are $c_0$, $c_1$, and $c_2$? Without that, there is no way of solving the problem.

Comment: the solution should be $$c_n=c_1 (-1)^n+c_2 3^n-1$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that:
$$C_{n+2}+C_{n+1}=3\left(C_{n+1}+C_n\right)+2^{n+2},$$ which gives
$$C_3+C_2=3\left(C_2+C_1\right)+2^3;$$
$$\frac{1}{3}\left(C_{4}+C_{3}\right)=C_{3}+C_2+\frac{1}{3}\cdot2^{4};$$
$$\frac{1}{3^2}\left(C_{5}+C_{4}\right)=\frac{1}{3}\left(C_{4}+C_3\right)+\frac{1}{3^2}\cdot2^{5};...$$
$$\frac{1}{3^{n-2}}\left(C_{n+1}+C_{n}\right)=\frac{1}{3^{n-3}}\left(C_{n}+C_{n-1}\right)+\frac{1}{3^{n-2}}\cdot2^{n+1},$$
which after summing gives
$$\frac{1}{3^{n-2}}\left(C_{n+1}+C_{n}\right)=3\left(C_{n+1}+C_n\right)+2^3+\frac{1}{3}\cdot2^4+\frac{1}{3^2}\cdot2^5+...+\frac{1}{3^{n-2}}\cdot2^{n+1}=$$
$$=3\left(C_{n+1}+C_n\right)+8\left(1+\frac{2}{3}+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2+...+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-2}\right)=$$
$$=3\left(C_{n+1}+C_n\right)+\frac{8\left(\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}-1\right)}{\frac{2}{3}-1}=3\left(C_{n+1}+C_n\right)+\frac{24\left(3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}\right)}{3^{n-1}},$$
which gives
$$C_{n+1}+C_n=3^{n-1}\left(C_2+C_1\right)+8\left(3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}\right)$$
and the rest is smooth.

Answer (score 0):

I think I already solved it.

$(1-2x-3x^2)C(x)=P(x)+\sum_{n \ge 0}(2^{n+2})x^n \Leftrightarrow$

$(1-2x-3x^2)C(x)=P(x)+4\sum_{n \ge 0}(2x)^n \Leftrightarrow$

$(1-2x-3x^2)C(x)=P(x)+\frac{4}{1-2x} \Leftrightarrow$
$\frac{Q(x)}{(1-2x)(1-2x-3x^3)}$

The denominator $(1-2x)(1-2x-3x^3)$ have zeros at $x=\frac{1}{2},x=\frac{1}{3},x=-1$

So $c_n=A(n)2^n+B(n)3^n+C(n)(-1)^n$

Cant I get more far??

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using generating functions, but another way uses linearity.

First we look for a specific solution of the form $c_n=T2^n$ which gives us $$4T\cdot2^n-4T\cdot2^n-3T\cdot2^n=4\cdot2^n$$ so that $-3T=4$ and $T=-\frac 43$

Now note that if $d_{n+2}-2d_{n+1}-3d_n=0$ then $c_n+d_n$ is another solution of the original equation.

Then if $p,q$ are the roots of $x^2-2x-3=0$ then we can choose $d_n=Ap^n+Bq^n$

We have $p=3, q=-1$

The values of $A$ and $B$ are undetermined. We note that the first two values of $c_n$ determine all the rest, and determine values of $A$ and $B$.

Note that, because the coefficient of $2^n$ is related to the particular solution of the inhomogeneous equation, this can be determined from the information you have. The two other coefficients cannot be determined from the information you have given, but are constant (independent of $n$).

So you need to be clear about the form of the solution you expect, and particularly what you expect the coefficients to be. Check out what happens when the roots of the quadratic are equal, or there is an exponential term in the inhomogeneous part which matches a root of the equation.